# I want to know how can I pass the a multiple values from php to jquery see the situation below

Tags: php, jquery

Example I have this line of code in PHP, and I want to pass these values when button is click and receive it by the jquery. How should I do this? I have started this codes and I don't know what is the next step on it.

PHP Code:

```
    <?php

echo '<button>Get the values</button>';
$name = 'sample name';
$age = 'sample age';
$add = 'sample add';

?>
```

JQuery Code:

```
   $(function() {
    $('button').live('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'recieve.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: { get_name: pass_name, get_age: pass_age, get_add: pass_add  },
            success:function(){

            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you not just get php to echo out the variables in the JS. Like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('button').live('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'recieve.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: { get_name: <?=$name ?>, get_age: <?=age ?>, get_add: <?=add ?>  },
        success:function(){

        }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: do i still need to echo $name and etc in php?

Comment: '<?=' is the equivalent of '<?php echo'. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to print the PHP values in a JSON variable and then access the values directly in JS. In this manner you can put your JS code in a different file and no need to be parse by PHP interpreter.

```
<?php
$my_values = array(
    'name' => 'Sample name',
    'age' => 'Sample age',
    'add' => 'Sample add',
);
?>
<html>
  <head>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var my_values = <?php print json_encode($my_values); ?>;

      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('button').live('click', function() {
          $.ajax({
            url: 'recieve.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: { get_name: my_values.name, get_age: my_values.age, get_add: my_values.add },
            success:function() {

            }
          });
      });
     });

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button>Get the values</button>
  </body>
</html>
```